# Make nose test runner show logging even if tests pass

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, nose

I am using `nosetests test.py` to run unit tests:

```
import unittest
import logging


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pass(self):
        logging.getLogger('do_not_want').info('HIDE THIS')
        logging.getLogger('test').info('TEST PASS')
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

    def test_fail(self):
        logging.getLogger('do_not_want').info('HIDE THIS')
        logging.getLogger('test').info('TEST FAIL')
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

When test fails, it prints out all logging info. I can use `--logging-filter` to filer out only some loggers:

```
nosetests test.py --verbosity=2 --logging-filter=test
test_fail (test.Test) ... FAIL
test_pass (test.Test) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_fail (test.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 14, in test_fail
    self.assertEqual(True, False)
AssertionError: True != False
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
test: INFO: TEST FAIL
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

**However, it does not show anything when tests pass.**

I would like to see output of one specific logger when tests pass. I have found that I can use `-s` to show all stdout / stderr text which is not exactly what I need - it prints everything. I tried to play with various settings such as `--nologcapture`, `--nocapture`, or `--logging-filter` but I was not able to get desired effect.

Comment: The logcapture plugin is only ~250 lines. You can probably subclass or adapt it quite easily to do what you want. You can find it [here](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/plugins/logcapture.py).

Comment: @Fenikso Did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: @Stefan No, it does not seem to exist in Nose. I am using a few ugly workarounds when needed, such as writing to file.

Comment: @Fenikso Thank you for your answer. It's a shame that nose doesn't support that...

Answer (score 25):

`nosetests --help` does not make this obvious AT ALL, but the answer is the `--debug` flag. This flag takes as an argument the name of the logger that you'd like to receive messages from.

Here's a slightly modified version of the OP's code:

```
# test.py
import unittest
import logging

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pass(self):
        logging.getLogger('hide.this').info('HIDE THIS')
        logging.getLogger('show.this').info('TEST PASS')
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

    def test_fail(self):
        logging.getLogger('hide.this').info('HIDE THIS')
        logging.getLogger('show.this').info('TEST FAIL')
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

For this example, `nosetests test.py --debug=show.this` should do the trick.

Comment: How would you do this for the root logger (e.g. `logging.debug('HELP')`) -- I tried `--debug=root` and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart try `--nocapture` to not capture anything

Comment: `--debug=root` works for me with nosetests version 1.3.7. I have NO `logging.basicConfig` in my sources, maybe that is important.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

In my case I use:

> nosetest -v -s

-s, --nocapture
Don't capture stdout (any stdout output will be printed immediately) [NOSE_NOCAPTURE]

HTH