# How to make nose print logging output from the root logger

Tags: python, logging, nose

How can I make nose print all logging output even for tests that pass?

(This [highly voted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565562/make-nose-test-runner-show-logging-even-if-tests-pass#comment67134718_39009116) on [Make nose test runner show logging even if tests pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565562/make-nose-test-runner-show-logging-even-if-tests-pass) asks the same question)